# How i can draw additional x-axis on point 0 of y-axis in d3 graph

Tags: jquery, d3.js, charts, multiline

I want to draw additional line on x-axis which appear at 0 point  in y-axis. chart is created on dynamic values so can not provide fixed position. It requires to read the position of x-axis where point 0 appears then draw line.
We can not bisect line as 0 position can be anywhere in line not specifically in middle.

Code for current graph is added below

Current graph:

[image: current graph]

Expected graph:

[image: expected graph]

```js
var data = [{
  "ErrorMessage": null,
  "Ymin": -30,
  "Ymax": 40,
  "Xmin": "2021-04-01 00:00:00",
  "Xmax": "2021-04-08 00:00:00",
  "Points": [{
      Date: "2021-04-01 06:59:06",
      Value: 3.43,
      Label: "2021-04-01 06:59:06",
      data: "BOX"
    },
    {
      Date: "2021-04-02 07:02:05",
      Value: -18.43,
      Label: "2021-04-02 07:02:05",
      data: "BOX"
    },
    {
      Date: "2021-04-03 07:12:06",
      Value: 5.43,
      Label: "2021-04-03 07:12:06",
      data: "BOX"
    },
    {
      Date: "2021-04-04 07:16:07",
      Value: 20.43,
      Label: "2021-04-04 07:16:07",
      data: "BOX"
    },
    {
      Date: "2021-04-03 05:12:20",
      Value: 3.43,
      Label: "2021-04-03 05:12:20",
      data: "Ball"
    },
    {
      Date: "2021-04-05 06:59:06",
      Value: 3.43,
      Label: "2021-04-05 06:59:06",
      data: "Ball"
    },
    {
      Date: "2021-04-06 07:02:05",
      Value: 18.43,
      Label: "2021-04-06 07:02:05",
      data: "Ball"
    },
    {
      Date: "2021-04-07 07:12:06",
      Value: 5.43,
      Label: "2021-04-07 07:12:06",
      data: "Ball"
    },
    {
      Date: "2021-04-07 07:16:07",
      Value: -20.43,
      Label: "2021-04-07 07:16:07",
      data: "BallC"
    }
  ]
}];

function loadChart(data) {
  var points = parseData(data.Points);
  chartDataLoaded(points[0], "#chart", "#my_dataviz", "#metric-tooltip", "V")
}

function chartDataLoaded(data, chartName, legendName, toolTipName, chartTitle, axisTitle) {
  var points = parseData(data.Points);
  drawMultilineData(points, data.Xmin, data.Xmax, data.Ymin, data.Ymax, chartName, legendName, toolTipName, chartTitle, axisTitle);
}

function chartDataFailed(data) {
  alert("Failed to load chart data");
}

function parseData(points) {
  var timeParser = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");

  var arr = [];
  for (var i in points) {
    arr.push({
      date: timeParser(points[i].Date), // Date
      value: points[i].Value, // Convert string to number
      label: points[i].Label,
      name: points[i].data
    });
  }
  console.log(arr);
  var expensesByName = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    })
    .entries(arr);
  console.log(expensesByName);
  return expensesByName;
}


chartDataLoaded(data[0], "#chart", "#my_dataviz", "#metric-tooltip", "test", "V")

function drawMultilineData(data, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, chartName, legendName, toolTipName, chartTitle, axisTitle) {

  //#region define outline and parameter
  var width = 500;
  var height = 300;
  var margin = 100;

  var duration = 250;

  var lineOpacity = "0.25";
  var lineOpacityHover = "0.85";
  var otherLinesOpacityHover = "0.1";
  var lineStroke = "2px";
  var lineStrokeHover = "3px";

  var circleOpacity = '0.85';
  var circleOpacityOnLineHover = "0.25"
  var circleRadius = 4;
  var circleRadiusHover = 6;

  //#endregion

  //#region get user defined color or random
  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
  var colors = {
    
  };
  //#endregion

  //time parser for min and max
  var timeParser = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");

  //#region create axis and scale 
  var xScale = d3.scaleTime().rangeRound([0, width]).domain([timeParser(xmin), timeParser(xmax)]);
  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]).domain([ymin, ymax]);
  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(8);
  var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);


  /* Add SVG */
  var svg = d3.select(chartName).append("svg")
    .attr("width", (width + margin + 100) + "px") //added to increase x axis to edge
    .attr("height", (height + margin + 100) + "px") //added to increase y axis to edge
    .append('g')
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin}, ${margin})`);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + height + ')') //to start x-axis point
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-10,10)rotate(-45)")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append('text')
    .attr("y", 150)
    .attr("x", -30)
    .style("font-size", "14px")
    .style("font-weight", "bold")
    .attr("fill", "#000")
    .text(axisTitle)
  //#endregion

  
  //#region create lines

  /* Add line into SVG */
  var line = d3.line()
    .x(d => xScale(d.date))
    .y(d => yScale(d.value));


  let lines = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'lines');

  lines.selectAll('.line-group')
    .data(data).enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'line-group')
    .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
      svg.select(".title-text").remove();
      svg.append("text")
        .attr("class", "title-text")
        .style("fill", (colors[d.key] === undefined) ? color(d.key) : colors[d.key])
        .text(d.key)
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("x", (width - margin) / 2)
        .attr("y", 5);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      svg.select(".title-text").remove();
    })
    .append('path')
    .attr('class', 'line')
    .attr('d', d => line(d.values))
    .style('stroke', (d, i) => (colors[d.key] === undefined) ? color(d.key) : colors[d.key])
    .style('opacity', lineOpacity)
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      d3.selectAll('.line')
        .style('opacity', otherLinesOpacityHover);
      d3.selectAll('.circle')
        .style('opacity', circleOpacityOnLineHover);
      d3.select(this)
        .style('opacity', lineOpacityHover)
        .style("stroke-width", lineStrokeHover)
        .style("cursor", "pointer");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      d3.selectAll(".line")
        .style('opacity', lineOpacity);
      d3.selectAll('.circle')
        .style('opacity', circleOpacity);
      d3.select(this)
        .style("stroke-width", lineStroke)
        .style("cursor", "none");
    });

  //#endregion
  
  //#region create circle
  /* Add circles in the line */
  lines.selectAll("circle-group")
    .data(data).enter()
    .append("g")
    .style("fill", (d, i) => (colors[d.key] === undefined) ? color(d.key) : colors[d.key])
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(d => d.values).enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "circle")
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      d3.select(this)
        .style("cursor", "pointer")
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "text")
        .attr("x", d => xScale(d.date) + 5)
        .attr("y", d => yScale(d.value) - 10);
      return tooltip2.style("visibility", "visible");
    })
    .on("mousemove", function(d) {
      return tooltip2.style("left", (d3.mouse(this)[0]) + "px").style("top", (d3.mouse(this)[1]) + "px")
        .html("<span>" + d.label + "<br/>" + d.value + "</span>");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      d3.select(this)
        .style("cursor", "none")
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .selectAll(".text").remove();
      return tooltip2.style("visibility", "hidden");
    })
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", d => xScale(d.date))
    .attr("cy", d => yScale(d.value))
    .attr("r", circleRadius)
    .style('opacity', circleOpacity)
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("r", circleRadiusHover);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("r", circleRadius);
    });

  //#endregion 
}
```

```css
svg {
  font-family: Sans-Serif, Arial;
}

.line {
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}

.axis path {
  stroke: black;
}

.text {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.title-text {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="col-md-12 row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div id="chart"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="test.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code:

```
const yZero = yScale(0);
svg.append('line')
  .attr('x1', 0)
  .attr('x2', width)
  .attr('y1', yZero)
  .attr('y2', yZero)
  .style('stroke', '#000');
```

```js
var data = [{
  "ErrorMessage": null,
  "Ymin": -30,
  "Ymax": 40,
  "Xmin": "2021-04-01 00:00:00",
  "Xmax": "2021-04-08 00:00:00",
  "Points": [{
      Date: "2021-04-01 06:59:06",
      Value: 3.43,
      Label: "2021-04-01 06:59:06",
      data: "BOX"
    },
    {
      Date: "2021-04-02 07:02:05",
      Value: -18.43,
      Label: "2021-04-02 07:02:05",
      data: "BOX"
    },
    {
      Date: "2021-04-03 07:12:06",
      Value: 5.43,
      Label: "2021-04-03 07:12:06",
      data: "BOX"
    },
    {
      Date: "2021-04-04 07:16:07",
      Value: 20.43,
      Label: "2021-04-04 07:16:07",
      data: "BOX"
    },
    {
      Date: "2021-04-03 05:12:20",
      Value: 3.43,
      Label: "2021-04-03 05:12:20",
      data: "Ball"
    },
    {
      Date: "2021-04-05 06:59:06",
      Value: 3.43,
      Label: "2021-04-05 06:59:06",
      data: "Ball"
    },
    {
      Date: "2021-04-06 07:02:05",
      Value: 18.43,
      Label: "2021-04-06 07:02:05",
      data: "Ball"
    },
    {
      Date: "2021-04-07 07:12:06",
      Value: 5.43,
      Label: "2021-04-07 07:12:06",
      data: "Ball"
    },
    {
      Date: "2021-04-07 07:16:07",
      Value: -20.43,
      Label: "2021-04-07 07:16:07",
      data: "BallC"
    }
  ]
}];

function loadChart(data) {
  var points = parseData(data.Points);
  chartDataLoaded(points[0], "#chart", "#my_dataviz", "#metric-tooltip", "V")
}

function chartDataLoaded(data, chartName, legendName, toolTipName, chartTitle, axisTitle) {
  var points = parseData(data.Points);
  drawMultilineData(points, data.Xmin, data.Xmax, data.Ymin, data.Ymax, chartName, legendName, toolTipName, chartTitle, axisTitle);
}

function chartDataFailed(data) {
  alert("Failed to load chart data");
}

function parseData(points) {
  var timeParser = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");

  var arr = [];
  for (var i in points) {
    arr.push({
      date: timeParser(points[i].Date), // Date
      value: points[i].Value, // Convert string to number
      label: points[i].Label,
      name: points[i].data
    });
  }
  console.log(arr);
  var expensesByName = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    })
    .entries(arr);
  console.log(expensesByName);
  return expensesByName;
}


chartDataLoaded(data[0], "#chart", "#my_dataviz", "#metric-tooltip", "test", "V")

function drawMultilineData(data, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, chartName, legendName, toolTipName, chartTitle, axisTitle) {

  //#region define outline and parameter
  var width = 500;
  var height = 300;
  var margin = 100;

  var duration = 250;

  var lineOpacity = "0.25";
  var lineOpacityHover = "0.85";
  var otherLinesOpacityHover = "0.1";
  var lineStroke = "2px";
  var lineStrokeHover = "3px";

  var circleOpacity = '0.85';
  var circleOpacityOnLineHover = "0.25"
  var circleRadius = 4;
  var circleRadiusHover = 6;

  //#endregion

  //#region get user defined color or random
  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
  var colors = {
    
  };
  //#endregion

  //time parser for min and max
  var timeParser = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");

  //#region create axis and scale 
  var xScale = d3.scaleTime().rangeRound([0, width]).domain([timeParser(xmin), timeParser(xmax)]);
  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]).domain([ymin, ymax]);
  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(8);
  var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);


  /* Add SVG */
  var svg = d3.select(chartName).append("svg")
    .attr("width", (width + margin + 100) + "px") //added to increase x axis to edge
    .attr("height", (height + margin + 100) + "px") //added to increase y axis to edge
    .append('g')
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin}, ${margin})`);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + height + ')') //to start x-axis point
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-10,10)rotate(-45)")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append('text')
    .attr("y", 150)
    .attr("x", -30)
    .style("font-size", "14px")
    .style("font-weight", "bold")
    .attr("fill", "#000")
    .text(axisTitle)
  //#endregion

  
  //#region create lines

  /* Add line into SVG */
  var line = d3.line()
    .x(d => xScale(d.date))
    .y(d => yScale(d.value));

  const yZero = yScale(0);
  svg.append('line')
    .attr('x1', 0)
    .attr('x2', width)
    .attr('y1', yZero)
    .attr('y2', yZero)
    .style('stroke', '#000');

  let lines = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'lines');

  lines.selectAll('.line-group')
    .data(data).enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'line-group')
    .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
      svg.select(".title-text").remove();
      svg.append("text")
        .attr("class", "title-text")
        .style("fill", (colors[d.key] === undefined) ? color(d.key) : colors[d.key])
        .text(d.key)
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("x", (width - margin) / 2)
        .attr("y", 5);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      svg.select(".title-text").remove();
    })
    .append('path')
    .attr('class', 'line')
    .attr('d', d => line(d.values))
    .style('stroke', (d, i) => (colors[d.key] === undefined) ? color(d.key) : colors[d.key])
    .style('opacity', lineOpacity)
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      d3.selectAll('.line')
        .style('opacity', otherLinesOpacityHover);
      d3.selectAll('.circle')
        .style('opacity', circleOpacityOnLineHover);
      d3.select(this)
        .style('opacity', lineOpacityHover)
        .style("stroke-width", lineStrokeHover)
        .style("cursor", "pointer");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      d3.selectAll(".line")
        .style('opacity', lineOpacity);
      d3.selectAll('.circle')
        .style('opacity', circleOpacity);
      d3.select(this)
        .style("stroke-width", lineStroke)
        .style("cursor", "none");
    });

  //#endregion
  
  //#region create circle
  /* Add circles in the line */
  lines.selectAll("circle-group")
    .data(data).enter()
    .append("g")
    .style("fill", (d, i) => (colors[d.key] === undefined) ? color(d.key) : colors[d.key])
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(d => d.values).enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "circle")
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      d3.select(this)
        .style("cursor", "pointer")
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "text")
        .attr("x", d => xScale(d.date) + 5)
        .attr("y", d => yScale(d.value) - 10);
      return tooltip2.style("visibility", "visible");
    })
    .on("mousemove", function(d) {
      return tooltip2.style("left", (d3.mouse(this)[0]) + "px").style("top", (d3.mouse(this)[1]) + "px")
        .html("<span>" + d.label + "<br/>" + d.value + "</span>");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      d3.select(this)
        .style("cursor", "none")
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .selectAll(".text").remove();
      return tooltip2.style("visibility", "hidden");
    })
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", d => xScale(d.date))
    .attr("cy", d => yScale(d.value))
    .attr("r", circleRadius)
    .style('opacity', circleOpacity)
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("r", circleRadiusHover);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("r", circleRadius);
    });

  //#endregion 
}
```

```css
svg {
  font-family: Sans-Serif, Arial;
}

.line {
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}

.axis path {
  stroke: black;
}

.text {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.title-text {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="col-md-12 row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div id="chart"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="test.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Michael it is working now. Could you please suggest me any article for better understanding of d3 and also the code you provided that would be really helpful.

Comment: @manishraghu it looks like you manage D3 pretty good :) Just 2 points: you don't need jQuery with D3 (D3 does everything you need to work with SVG), and also try to use the latest version V6 instead of outdated V4

Comment: Thank you Michael :) One small thing if you could help with that, the new created line is little above the 0 tick I tried to align it by changing the yZero value but it is not linking properly. Is there any attribute or style I can use to link it with the tick.

Comment: You can add: `.style('stroke-width', 0.5)` or `.style('opacity', 0.5)` or just change the stroke color to gray  or  another less dominant than black `.style('stroke', 'gray')`